# Adding argument variable to filename in Textmate

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, textmate

Am trying to run a Python script which starts with

```
from sys import argv
```

How do I run the file and add a variable when I run the file in TextMate? I use the "Command - R" command to run the script.

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382902/textmate-command-line-arguments-for-python

Answer (score 0):

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750707/command-line-options-in-textmate), TextMate will ask for command-line arguments if you use Command-Shift-R.

Comment: should these be made duplicates of that?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382902/textmate-command-line-arguments-for-python) yes, [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750707/command-line-options-in-textmate) is a different question, but reveals an answer to this question. I could not link the duplicates because there were no upvoted or accepted answers yet.