# Command Line Options in Textmate

Tags: java, command-line, textmate

Usually when I code Java in TextMate, I use the command-shift-R
command to run a Java script with a main method. However, every time I do that a window pops up saying "Enter any command line options". I normally press OK with no arguments, and JavaMate works fine. Can someone elaborate what "Enter any command line options" means and its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments through the command line to a Java program. For example, you can call it like this:

```
java MyProgram.java --option --another-option --a-third-option=optional
```

Your Java program receives these command-line options via the `String[] args` parameter in its `main` method. You can do things with these options to tailor how the program is executed in response to them.

That window allows you to enter these command-line options when running the program with the keybinding.